# Forget to free up space...fail to upgrade to mojave

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave

I tried to upgrade my os to Mojave yesterday. Its all fine until I realized the installation process is fail. I assume its because of the lack of space in my hard drive.

Now I am stuck. Unable to log into my mac cause the mac is unable to access my osx hard drive partition. When boot, it will go to no entry logo. I'm able to enter recovery mode, trying to reinstall Mojave but fail. I also trying to mount the osx partition but unable to mount it. Trying to send command via terminal but terminal unable to access the partition.

What should I do...

Comment: what Mac, did you have HighSierra before

Comment: that is normally not possible, the installation package checks if you have enough space before starting.

Comment: Yes..i have high sierra before. I think so too. But thats only reason that comes to mind

Comment: try starting in Safe mode

Comment: Cant enter safe mode..its like the computer didnt know the location of the original osx. I set up filevault password 2 years ago and it ask for my password everytime i want to boot it up...this time. It didnt even ask my password

Comment: restore from back up or start from USB